# sorting items while pushing to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, date, sorting

I want to sort the date and time while pushing the items to an array. So far, I can sort just the date but not able to sort the time. If the same date has two times, then how do I sort the date first and then the timing for that date.

```
let items = [
{'id': 'id7', 'date': '2020-08-17', 'time': '05:02:54.000'},
{'id': 'id2', 'date': '2020-05-12', 'time': '02:09:57.000'}, 
{'id': 'id3', 'date': '2020-05-12', 'time': '03:04:44.000'}, //both the 2020-05-12 date has two timings so I want to sort these time too along with the date
{'id': 'id4', 'date': '2020-09-23', 'time': '07:16:23.000'}
];

const headers = [
'ID',
'Date',
'Time'
];

dataArr = []

items.forEach(item => {
    dataArr.push([
        item.id,
        item.date,
        item.time
    ]);
})
;
let sortedData = [headers, ...dataArr.sort((a, b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1]))];
```

final sorted array must look something like

```
['id': 'id2', 'date': '2020-05-12', 'time': '02:09:57.000'], 
['id': 'id3', 'date': '2020-05-12', 'time': '03:04:44.000'],
['id': 'id7', 'date': '2020-08-17', 'time': '05:02:54.000'],
['id': 'id4', 'date': '2020-09-23', 'time': '07:16:23.000']
```

Comment: `a[1]` doesn't make sense; your array contains objects.

Comment: I pushed into dataArr array and then compared @Pointy

Comment: Right, but `a` and `b` passed into the sort comparator will be references to the **objects** you pushed into the array. You need to compare `a.date` to `b.date` and `a.time` to `b.time`.

Comment: Make timestamp out of `date + time` and then compare

Comment: @Pointy it's working for me though for the date.

Comment: @Justinas but timestamp will be one single column. I want the date and time separately

Comment: @allhopelost Use it only for sorting as third column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

try to sort both date and time in a single sort function

```js
let ss = [
{'id': 'id7', 'date': '2020-08-17', 'time': '05:02:54.000'},
{'id': 'id2', 'date': '2020-05-12', 'time': '02:09:57.000'}, 
{'id': 'id3', 'date': '2020-05-12', 'time': '03:04:44.000'}, 
{'id': 'id4', 'date': '2020-09-23', 'time': '07:16:23.000'}
];

let dd = ss.sort((a,b)=>new Date(a.date+':'+a.time) - new Date(b.date+':'+b.time))

console.log(dd)
```

Comment: for some reason, in my code, it's showing in descending order for the time, although the date is looking fine. I tried it
```let sortedData = [headers, ...dataArr.sort((a,b)=>new Date(a[1]+':'+a[2]) - new Date(b[1]+':'+b[2]))];```

Answer (score 0):

```
let sortedData = [headers, ...dataArr.sort((a, b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1])==0 ? a[2].localeCompare(b[2]) : a[1].localeCompare(b[1]))];
```

```js
let items = [
{'id': 'id7', 'date': '2020-08-17', 'time': '05:02:54.000'}, 
{'id': 'id3', 'date': '2020-05-12', 'time': '03:04:44.000'},
{'id': 'id4', 'date': '2020-09-23', 'time': '07:16:23.000'},
{'id': 'id2', 'date': '2020-05-12', 'time': '02:09:57.000'}
];

const headers = [
'ID',
'Date',
'Time'
];

dataArr = []

items.forEach(item => {
    dataArr.push([
        item.id,
        item.date,
        item.time
    ]);
})
;
let sortedData = [headers, ...dataArr.sort((a, b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1])==0 ? a[2].localeCompare(b[2]) : a[1].localeCompare(b[1]))];
console.log(sortedData)
```

Comment: this didn't work either. the date is sorted but the time isn't

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
function compare (a,b) {
    if(a<b) return -1;
    else if(a>b) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

items.sort((a,b) => {
    let d = compare(a.date, b.date);
    if(d < 0) return -1;
    else if(d > 0) return 1;
    else {
         //Same date compare time
        let t = compare(a.time, b.time);
        if(t < 0) return -1;
        else if(t > 0) return 1;
        else return 0;


    }

});
```

This compares the date first. If dates differ, you don't need to compare time. If dates are same, you can compare time.